# socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-2.7

I have been crawling the twitter data using the twitter streaming api using tweepy in python script. I was able to crawl for some hours then it shows an error  "socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer". After few hrs(approx. 8hr) it starts crawling with no error. Even after changing the api key even then I am facing this error.

Comment: Can you restart the connection instantly, or is this error constantly reappearing for 8 hours? Can you switch your IP address in that time?

Comment: When i tried from another ip this is the error i am facing: ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol